# Cannot use directives two times in same view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I just encountered a new error the other day. I'm using my directive like this:

`<a sidebar-select-item="selectedItem" item-type="type1"></a>
<a sidebar-select-item="selectedItem" item-type="type2"></a>`

Where the directive looks like this:

```
.directive('sidebarSelectItem', ['$rootScope', 'SidebarService','$compile','$parse', function($rootScope, SidebarService, $compile, $parse){

    return {
        restrict:'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            sidebarSelectItem: "=sidebarSelectItem"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            //Removed code for readability
        }
    };

}])
```

The above looks sparse but has been cleaned for the essence of it. I have not experienced any issue with link only, but as soon as scope is part of the directive I get the following error:

```
Multiple directives [sidebarSelectItemtranslate, new/isolated{3}] asking for {4} on: {5}
```

Now I understand what it's saying, my main question is why does it act this way when I use an isolated scope? And is there any way to bypass this while maintaining the binding?

Comment: is `itemType` is directive with isolated scope??

Comment: ItemType is attained from attr, as it doesn't need to be bound